# Rails 5: loop through two tables with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following tables and associations:

```
class Discount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
end


class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :discount
end


create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.string "price"
  t.text "description"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end    


create_table "discounts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "percentage"
  t.date "from"
  t.date "until"
  t.integer "product_id", default: [], array: true
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_discounts_on_product_id", using: :gin
end
```

And I'm trying to loop through the products on the view and show the discounts on each product like this:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <%= number_to_currency product.price %>
   <%= product.title.capitalize %>
   <%= product.description.capitalize %>
     <% product.discount.each do |discount| %>
     <%= discount %>%</span>
<% end %>
```

If i just loop through the products everything works fine but when I add the code to loop through the discounts I'm getting the following error:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "137"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
: SELECT  "discounts".* FROM "discounts" WHERE "discounts"."product_id" = $1 LIMIT $2
```

Any Idea on what I might be missing here and how to make this work?

**Update 1**

Ok I did this like many suggested:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableDiscountsProducts discount product

class CreateJoinTableDiscountsProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_join_table :discounts, :products do |t|
       t.index [:discount_id, :product_id]
       t.index [:product_id, :discount_id]
    end
  end
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :discounts
end

class Discount < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end


<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <%= number_to_currency product.price %>
   <%= product.title.capitalize %>
   <%= product.description.capitalize %>
      <% product.discounts.each do |discount| %>
        <%= discount.percentage %>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The error doesn't appear anymore but the discounts don't appear either. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You will be fighting Rails conventions with this `array`setup you have. You should create a join-table `discounts_products`

Comment: Hey @Iceman, and then if I do this will work? `<% product.discount.each do |discount| %> <%= discount.precentage %> <%end%>`

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html Have a read thru this, it's all explained there very well.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :discount
end
```

which means each product has only one discount.

Then the discount can be obtained by:

```
 <%= product.discount %>
```

if one product has many discounts, then change in model as:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :discounts
end
```

If the association is changed then below each loop will work:

```
 <% product.discount.each do |discount| %>
     <%= discount %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nandhini unfortunately I'm getting the same error as before. Please keep in mind that the product_id column is an array which I'm storing multiple product ids.

Comment: @Dev not sure why your product_id is an array; this is very wrong.

Comment: @ Roc Khalil, I want one discount to be associated with many products. Is my approach on this wrong?

Comment: if product_id is an array you cannot extract product.discount. It is better to have a mapping table which maps products to discounts. This case is used where, one discount belongs to many products and one product has many discounts. check https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: So I should change the associations to has_and_belongs_to_many? is this what you're suggesting?

Comment: exactly the best way to do it . a similar case https://teamtreehouse.com/library/has-and-belongs-to-many-associations